# Can razorpages have a common base class beside pagemodel?

Tags: asp.net-core

Can I create a base class to use for several razorpages, as long as the base class inherits from PageModel? I have not seen any examples using this approach, but it would seem like a good way to setup dependencies that need to be injected.  Rather than inject on each page model constructor, do it once in the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inherit from multiple classes, c# allows inheriting from only one base class. But you still able to implement multiple interfaces beside the base PageModel.

As a workaround, your base class can inherit from another base class that has `PageModel` as base class and so on... but try not to avoid the [kiss principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (see [Programming principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Programming_principles))

```cs
public class MyBasePageModel : PageModel
{
    // custom implementations...
}
```

Then apply to `IndexModel`:

```cs
public class IndexModel : MyBasePageModel
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was doing but I had a bunch of copiler errors once I did this - not due to use a base class but something causing my code formatting nuking a curly brace further down the page.  The compiler was warning about namespace collisions and bunch of other stuff. Once I found and fixed that, im back in action.  I was pretty sure I could do this since I have taken the similar approach with MVC applications, using a base class for my controllers.